# Block script from hanging when islice is used on a multiprocessing Queue

Tags: python, multiprocessing, python-itertools

I have an iterable Python class that wraps around a multiprocessing generator. There are use cases where only a subset of what is generated is necessary, so it gets wrapped in islice.

However, the call hangs when islice is used, I guess due to the underlying multiprocessing Process not being aware that things are over.

A minimally functioning example is as follows:

```
from itertools import islice
import multiprocessing as mp

STOP_MSG = 'STOP!'

def generator(queue, max_val):
  for i in range(max_val):
    queue.put(i)
  queue.put(STOP_MSG)

class GeneratorMPProc:
  def __init__(self, max_val):
    self.max_val = max_val

  def __iter__(self):
    queue = mp.Queue()
    feeder_process = mp.Process(
      target=generator,
      args=(
        queue,
        self.max_val,
      ))
    feeder_process.start()
    msg = queue.get()
    while msg != STOP_MSG:
      yield msg
      msg = queue.get()
    feeder_process.join()

if __name__ == '__main__':
  max_val = 0xFFFFFFFFF
  end_val = 10

  psm = GeneratorMPProc(max_val)
  rsm = [i for i in islice(psm, end_val)]
```

How do I fix this so that it terminates correctly even when islice or any subset selector is used?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `isllice` call is not going to return until `GeneratorMPProc.iter` returns and that will take quite a while with `max_val` set to `0xFFFFFFFFF` (writing to a queue is not the fastest operation and this will also use up a bit of resources). In other words, "things are *not* over" until your generator function ends and thus your `multiprocess.Process` actually ends and can be joined.

**Set `max_val` to a value such as 20 and your program will terminate readily enough.**

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #max_val = 0xFFFFFFFFF
    max_val = 20
    end_val = 10

    psm = GeneratorMPProc(max_val)
    rsm = [i for i in islice(psm, end_val)]
    print(rsm)
```

Prints:

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

**Update**

You might want to consider starting the "generator" process with an extra argument `daemon=True` to make it a daemon process and then remove `feeder_process.join()` altogether from method `__iter__`. The code will then work even with your original `max_val`.

```
  def __iter__(self):
    queue = mp.Queue()
    feeder_process = mp.Process(
      target=generator,
      args=(
        queue,
        self.max_val,
      ),
      daemon=True
    )
    feeder_process.start()
    msg = queue.get()
    while msg != STOP_MSG:
      yield msg
      msg = queue.get()
```

Comment: Yup, the update solved it. Thanks! The reason I can't take the first approach is because the actual code relies on something very computationally heavy per item, so just asking that maximum computations be reduced doesn't really work.